# Open Satellite Map Tiles for offline use

Tags: geospatial

I'm building an offline gis app and need satellite tiles. Download and use of most tile providers like google are against their terms of condition. Is there any open/free source for such data?

I can use NASA Blue Marble NG and generate tiles from their images, but the scale is 500 meters and is too coarse grained for my usage.

Comment: What sort of resolution would suit your needs?

Comment: @aidenprice 1~2 meters would be best.

Comment: Also, do you have a particular area of interest? Keep in mind that high resolution tiles over a large area will increase the size of your app dramatically.

Comment: @aidenprice Yes, I'm looking for Iran's map.

Comment: I can think of a commercial (paid) product that would suit your needs exactly, but it's probably not polite to mention it on an Open Data website.

Comment: @mehraban:where to download satellite map tiles for offline usgase please help me.I stuck in my application.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using a non-FOSS source, it looks like the MapBox iOS and Android libraries allow caching satellite imagery.

Links:

- https://www.mapbox.com/help/offline-satellite/
- https://www.mapbox.com/help/mobile-offline/

Comment: Their [terms of use](https://www.mapbox.com/help/mobile-offline/#tile-ceiling--limits) doesn't allow end user to redistribute offline maps downloaded from Mapbox servers.